# How to avoid pop-up appearing for a second randomly on different pages

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I write UI tests using Selenium Webdriver 2.0 with Python 3.6. A popup appears randomly, that causes focus to be lost, causing my test to fail. It appears for one second, randomly on different pages, and doesn't exist in the DOM, how to win it?

What I've tried:
Try/except
Wait for element

Sometimes these methods help but it's unreal to add it on every step to wait or catch that element

I expect my tests shouldn't fail because of that popup.

[here it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhYto.jpg)

Comment: can you tell us more about those popups is that an Browser or application which browser you are using and if possible then please share the source of the page that you are trying to automate ^.^

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome 73.0, source: eldorado.ru
Im not sure you will see that popup on page(, all i know this popup has a class 'flocktory-widget'

Comment: at which point you are getting the popup and is that a browser popup or application popup because i am not getting any popup in application

Comment: Try to run chrome in incognito and go to page https://www.eldorado.ru/today_only/ , probably you'll see it

Comment: Didnt get the popup. Is it a browser popup or is it html on the webpage?

Comment: it is html on the webpage but it doesn't exist in current DOM

Comment: Popup doesn't appear for me too. Without a way to replicate the problem it's impossible to give you a solution.

Comment: Catch the exception so you can watch out for it. Or always click focus somewhere before continuing.